# DB doesn't respond after N calls

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring, websphere, mybatis

my web app call(via mybatis) the DB(sqlserver 2008) with websphere. Many times it blocks after N calls(N select) and the web app doesn't respond. Then I have to restart the Websphere.

```
for (Integer idMovimento: idMovimenti)
                {

                    try{
                        Movimenti tmpMov = selectByPrimaryKeyForMovimentiRAC(idMovimento);

                    scartInputParam.setIdMovimento(idMovimento);
                    List<Scarto> tmpSc = movimentiDAO.selectScarti(scartInputParam);
```

It blocks in the last select every time.

Any suggestion?
Have I to configure the WAS or there are other tricks?
And can I recall the query after some time?

Comment: Generally no or wrong transaction setup leading to leaking connections.

Comment: But with few calls it works fine. The problem is after 30 select's call that stops and I have to stop and restart the server. How can I do with the problem?

Comment: Are there any exceptions when the web app doesn't respond?  What version of WebSphere?

Comment: Websphere v9. I controlled the log file and this is printed         WSVR0605W: Thread “WebContainer : 1” has been active for 678779 milliseconds and may be hung. There are 1 threads in total in the server that may be hung.

Comment: And after the stacktrace

Comment: @travis_91 That is what I'm saying... It will probably work for the size of your connection pool and after that stops working. This is due to non or absent transaction management or manually messing around with connections and not properly releasing them.

Comment: If that were the case I would expect a connection wait timeout exception to the be thrown, unless he has changed the value from its default of 180 seconds.  Depending on what state things are stuck in (ex. stuck on a socket read from the database vs the connection just sitting in use but not doing anything) there are some timeouts you could configure, but it seems they would just be covering up the problem instead of fixing it.  See here for details: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzamy/50/admin/help/udat_conpoolset.html.

Comment: You could also purge the pool when you are in this state so you don't have to restart the server, but once again it would just be covering up the issue: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21220832

Comment: @AlexMotley Why just covering the problem?How can I fix the problem? The only way that I can do this is to increase the connectio timeout I think

Comment: Unfortunately, given the current information there are too many possibilities for me to guess what the problem is.  It seems something is exhausting your connection pool, anything to increase the pool size or wait times is just covering up this issue and it likely will only increase the time it takes for the problem to reappear rather than eliminate the problem.  You could try using showPoolContents when you are hung to give you a better idea of what is holding/leaking connections: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385033

Comment: If you're on at least 9.0.0.4 here's a new method for troubleshooting long running transactions: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/rtrb_jdbclong.html

Comment: @AlexMotley@M. Deinum  But normally how has to work the database and was with a huge mount of records? I thing that there are some configuration that fix the problem or no? The only thing I can do is to change the connection pool time

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I changed my query adding join into the select query, in this way I avoid to call the database N time and I put all the result into a list. Then I worked with java without any needless call.